# Using the script argument with remote-exec - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am attempting to use the script argument with the remote-exec terraform Provisioner. According to the documentation, the script argument does the following:

*script - This is a path (relative or absolute) to a local script that will be copied to the
remote resource and then executed. This cannot be provided with inline or scripts.*

Here is a link to the doc:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html

Here is the code:

```
    script = [
    "./scripts/provision.sh"
    ]
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on main.tf line 86, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
86:    script = [
87:      "./scripts/provision.sh",
88:    ]

Inappropriate value for attribute "script": string required.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to TF - script does not take a list, which is defined by using [ ] square brackets. The solution is to use

```
script = "./scripts/provision.sh"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the doc it says:

**You cannot pass any arguments to scripts using the script or scripts arguments to this provisioner**. If you want to specify arguments, upload the script with the file provisioner and then use inline to call it. Example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "script.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/script.sh",
      "/tmp/script.sh args",
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, I would recommend using inline over script/scripts(my personal preference). If you need to use scripts use without braces.

Let me know if you need more help with remote exec.